# Oracle: selfcopying data from Oracle tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Application has different versions. Each version has it's own set of values in each table. I need to provide functionality to copy data from one version to another. Problem :

By inserting data I am trying to insert Ids which has already been in use in this table. So, I need to change ids of components which I want to insert but I must save relationship between those components. How cat I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a master table which has a surrogate key as your primary key.  A numeric value of type NUMBER(9) works well. You can create a sequence and trigger to automatically insert this.

The rest of the table is the column of your current table plus a column to indicate which version the row is for.

For simplicity you may wish to create views on top of the table along the lines of

`select * from master_table where version_id = ####;`

To copy the data from one version to another this will work:

```
Insert into master_table  seq_master_table.nextval, new version_id,..... 
from master_table
where version_id = ####;
```